# Why is my Scala class not visible to its matching test class?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am starting out in Scala with SBT, making a Hello World program.

Here's my project layout:

[image]

I've made sure to download the very latest JDK and Scala, and configure my Project Settings. Here's my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Coursera_Scala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
```

`Hello.scala` itself compiles okay:

```
package demo

class Hello {
  def sayHelloTo(name: String) = "Hello, $name!"
}
```

However, my accompanying `HelloTest.scala` does not. Here's the test:

```
package demo

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class HelloTest extends FunSuite {

  test("testSayHello") {
    val result = new Hello.sayHelloTo("Scala")
    assert(result == "Hello, Scala!")
  }

}
```

Here's the error:

```
Error:(8, 22) not found: value Hello
    val result = new Hello.sayHello("Scala")
                 ^
```

In addition to the compile error, Intellij shows errors "Cannot resolve symbol" for the symbols `Hello`, `assert`, and `==`. This leads me to believe that the build is set up incorrectly, but then wouldn't there be an error on the import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this expression:

```
new Hello.sayHelloTo("Scala")
```

This creates a new instance of the class `sayHelloTo` defined on the value `Hello`. However, there is no value `Hello`, just the class `Hello`.

You want to write this:

```
(new Hello).sayHelloTo("Scala")
```

This creates a new instance of the class `Hello` and calls `sayHelloTo` on the instance.

Comment: Ah, so the error is that I took it for granted that the `new` operator would have very high precedence :-) Thank you.

Comment: the takeaway is that you did not have an object yet

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `new Hello().sayHelloTo(...)`. Writing () should create a new instance and then call the method.